# How much fat can the body absorb? Implications for daily fat distribution

Tags: nutrition, fat-metabolism

This question is named analogous to this research: *How much protein can the body use in a single meal for muscle-building? Implications for daily protein distribution* http://ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC5828430

**How many grams of lipids can the body absorb in one sitting?** (I ask because a strict vegetarian or vegan diet is characteristically low in fat. Therefore, I consume extra virgin olive oil and nuts.)

[image]

[image]

Most of the research on pubmed.gov is about oral lipid drug administration/absorption. This work that seemed to come close is over my head and just doesn't seem to specify:

*Intestinal Lipid Absorption and Transport* by C T Phan 1 and P Tso

PMID: 11229876 DOI: 10.2741/phan

https://www.bioscience.org/2001/v6/af/A612/fulltext.htm

---

Image sources: Cronometer.com and Jackedonplants.co.uk

Comment: just a piece of advice, "nuts" covers a lot of things many common nuts are very low in saturated fat, and so its olive oil.

Answer (score 0):

> Indeed, lipid fecal loss remains below 5% (w/w) even in situation of
>   high fat supply in healthy humans, [30].

All about those guts and bowls folks!

[image]

`Niot, I., Poirier, H., Tran, T. T. T., & Besnard, P. (2009). Intestinal absorption of long-chain fatty acids: Evidence and uncertainties. Progress in Lipid Research, 48(2), 101–115. doi:10.1016/j.plipres.2009.01.001`

https://sci-hub.tw/10.1016/j.plipres.2009.01.001

[30] Ross AC. Overview of retinoid metabolism. J Nutr 1993;123:346–50

---

The issue remaining is how Ross' work doesn't seem to say anything about lipids. Yet, it appears from the mice studies nearly all fat is absorbed (except for ones with special conditions).

`Ross, A. C. (1993). Overview of Retinoid Metabolism. The Journal of Nutrition, 123(suppl_2), 346–350. doi:10.1093/jn/123.suppl_2.346`

https://sci-hub.tw/https://doi.org/10.1093/jn/123.suppl_2.346

Comment: Your first sentence answers the question. Or practically: If the amount of fat you consume does not make your stools fatty (steathorrhea), it means you are absorbing most of it.

Comment: Maybe the amount of bile liver is able to produce and gall to secrete is some super natural limit.

Comment: @Jan or gut bacteria is breaking it all down inot something else.